# Disable Xamarin Mac Agent dialogue in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

Every time I create a new project, using the template `Cross Platform App (Xamarin)`, in Visual Studio Community 2017 the following dialogue appears:

[image]

For the time being I am in the process of learning Xamarin and not interested in using Xamarin.iOS. Does anyone know how to disable this dialogue so that it doesn't appear *every* time I create a new Xamarin project?

Comment: Either remove the iOS project or unload the project in VS.

Comment: @Cheesebaron The dialogue appears during the solution creation process. After the project has been created I can delete the iOS project but the dialogue has already popped up.

Comment: I guess there is no way of not making it pop up then

Comment: try to remove the ios part in VS installer

Comment: I personally want to keep the iOS project loaded in case I refactor parts of my shared code, but have no interest in actually building the project while I'm in VS/Windows. The popup comes up every time the solution is loaded though, would be great if it could be disabled somehow.